# Merge function duplicates all rows

Tags: r, merge, duplicates

There seem to be lots of similar questions, but I cannot find the answer I need. So hopefully someone is able to help me.

Here are my two dataframes:

```
    structure(list(Country = c("Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina","Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", 
"Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", 
"Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", 
"Cameroon", "Canada", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", 
"China", "China, Hong Kong SAR", "China, Macao SAR", "Colombia", 
"Comoros", "Congo", "Costa Rica", "Côte d'Ivoire", "Croatia", 
"Curaçao", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "D.R. of the Congo", "Denmark", 
"Djibouti", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", 
"Equatorial Guinea", "Estonia", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", 
"Finland", "France", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", 
"Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Haiti", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", 
"Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", 
"Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", 
"Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's DR", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", 
"Liberia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Malawi", 
"Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", 
"Mexico", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", "Mozambique", 
"Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
"Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "North Macedonia", "Norway", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", 
"Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Republic of Korea", "Republic of Moldova", 
"Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Lucia", "Sao Tome and Principe", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", 
"Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "Spain", 
"Sri Lanka", "St. Vincent and the Grenadines", "State of Palestine", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", 
"Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Thailand", "Togo", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
"Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "U.R. of Tanzania: Mainland", 
"Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", 
"United States of America", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", 
"Viet Nam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe", "Albania", "Algeria", 
"Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", 
"Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
"Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", 
"Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", 
"Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Central African Republic", 
"Chad", "Chile", "China", "China, Hong Kong SAR", "China, Macao SAR", 
"Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Costa Rica", "Côte d'Ivoire", 
"Croatia", "Curaçao", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "D.R. of the Congo", 
"Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", 
"El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Estonia", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", 
"Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", 
"Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Haiti", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", 
"Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", 
"Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", 
"Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's DR", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", 
"Liberia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Malawi", 
"Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", 
"Mexico", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", "Mozambique", 
"Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
"Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "North Macedonia", "Norway", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", 
"Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Republic of Korea", "Republic of Moldova", 
"Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Lucia", "Sao Tome and Principe", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", 
"Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "Spain", 
"Sri Lanka", "St. Vincent and the Grenadines", "State of Palestine", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", 
"Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Thailand", "Togo", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
"Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "U.R. of Tanzania: Mainland", 
"Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", 
"United States of America", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", 
"Viet Nam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), outcomes = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("change_log_GDP_per_cap_1965_1990", 
"change_log_GDP_per_cap_1990_2015"), class = "factor"), value = c(NA, 
0.578640766531612, NA, NA, 0.495306867140096, NA, NA, 0.502330777653556, 
0.803114233961656, NA, NA, NA, -0.0993172653981915, 0.53808861725514, 
NA, 0.674597690030525, NA, -0.298127667954598, NA, 0.216504524313533, 
NA, 2.56081101010179, 0.744222824189625, NA, NA, 0.258214133266048, 
0.317611686261003, 0.8788161166173, NA, 0.421490462104297, 0.62364065369507, 
-0.232836544661687, -0.25227764221683, 0.231558185654343, 0.706630519833809, 
1.40191885822497, NA, 0.6181432134753, 0.408454749819774, 0.599584651840675, 
0.378345211978761, 0.111507643407153, NA, NA, 1.33884428004283, 
NA, -0.586751232211046, 0.474943966789859, NA, 0.627304433189133, 
0.317205519888644, 0.87991776954798, 0.0520672035501422, 0.285152006511415, 
NA, NA, 0.201711542768606, 0.769230971131345, 0.78251833772058, 
0.650001049678337, 0.640096625729845, -0.0303826601505452, NA, 
0.733078935225739, -0.389445841048811, 0.811272158246615, NA, 
0.347761117146236, 0.0460198222610888, 0.252620248084438, 0.0908892376466257, 
0.194886362609917, NA, 0.6418754594287, 0.129860579793292, 1.24788076169943, 
0.0596726474866065, NA, 0.846327343910559, 0.692715318495344, 
1.04082900921705, -0.178497178067447, 1.19255811694978, -0.105838641466363, 
NA, 0.109606385549342, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.303236240856323, 
-0.949968922781927, NA, 0.767732347388234, -0.161463624976531, 
0.020231695956479, 1.01233514958369, NA, 0.273235768821569, 1.7586551566631, 
-0.00512803730690603, 0.707921737818435, 0.467617173114609, NA, 
NA, 0.634355958220369, -0.0789716727055412, 0.0814288107000012, 
-0.243613157682208, 0.31709721264631, 0.610652584945905, 0.256647954302224, 
-0.781050134405546, -0.653436784876962, -1.60341160431009, NA, 
0.637654669091246, NA, 0.541902824704716, 0.513807926378716, 
0.731034519303526, 0.0790048395384364, 0.547280287550333, NA, 
0.980396213589966, NA, 2.20962119039451, NA, 1.24070927417225, 
NA, 0.292149277989863, NA, NA, NA, -0.0146454022990596, NA, 0.973529653896689, 
0.234827951040259, 1.84165010186193, NA, NA, 0.231253973970862, 
0.756869751851962, 0.0928048611587418, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.511571399256075, 
0.469489935700883, -0.788333302649573, 1.76276690269169, NA, 
1.29149886770248, 0.109795534430917, 0.332264957334248, 1.06833555366236, 
0.683041196894621, NA, -0.305200676581399, -0.0697266221845751, 
NA, NA, 0.53776863243352, 0.548279184993683, 0.252697187479718, 
NA, 0.108634530140673, NA, NA, -0.809370440030817, 0.763010604986301, 
1.16118080105539, 0.345268208529435, 0.674459564759276, 0.375884558385717, 
1.12626530940127, 0.397946473384152, -0.00253749454397934, 0.533919266428686, 
0.670508443689885, 0.729139168827412, 0.138553807251364, 0.964924076948211, 
0.831001408021516, -0.107867285904469, 0.226109406112348, 0.565002710947052, 
0.284613448691427, 0.49671777747743, 1.08871795603012, 0.965320933057071, 
2.0824942302721, 0.909321382997916, 0.90572923716188, 0.0745240787206782, 
0.56342165427044, 0.518270859785026, -0.14261584736499, 1.11596521067868, 
1.07746977455876, 0.234995617759376, 0.351972663095612, -0.443934223486251, 
0.400139141337132, 1.11273343990489, 1.55236005828284, 0.801714457394146, 
1.36083105766367, 0.605176130472083, -0.214126332742843, 0.525398196260118, 
0.727131320016225, 0.363476755488312, 0.592511243723756, NA, 
0.393009253653243, 0.395363456453468, -0.500484422514334, 0.576601147212303, 
0.212354523986997, 1.10506821483667, 0.58045978480669, 1.60319871386148, 
1.00648719095641, 2.34871552055859, 0.989017399345231, 0.296900628912704, 
0.69635119246042, 0.397167906662684, 0.476036716075047, 0.455084710211471, 
0.387214183430407, -0.0991552203097266, -0.0267406304735509, 
0.584919113694179, 0.578109146112334, 0.42027754849506, 0.959093836130545, 
0.702232988685832, -0.489186633293355, 0.0667617953291728, 0.272108047914668, 
0.430569823721677, 0.723918391584105, 0.418479258591489, 1.46692343017624, 
1.13810360000623, 1.58208109756767, 1.14483586081786, 1.34109776560516, 
0.547783112654397, 0.378827744259436, 0.443336132108021, 0.390603398945073, 
0.979563275303992, 0.677796146444582, 0.30945873654342, 0.811130009728783, 
-0.698518017728585, 1.5965365998623, 0.428944840390766, 1.35340343539671, 
0.72302713452681, 0.0165685053242486, 0.73992426940646, 0.834336855944846, 
0.169723309384593, 0.124024117537306, 1.09861308721801, 1.19942465415223, 
1.19380578812553, 0.978983580563993, 0.438319759789805, 0.724114030801147, 
0.450473671944929, 1.23922185191996, 0.394164965021167, 0.657274225873365, 
0.855678052044124, 1.85192687683034, 0.86999914293389, 0.827673817687534, 
0.601326117535573, 0.56384253841845, 0.502420140731956, 0.0558758572526301, 
1.77296464408553, 0.825623246808037, 0.795992808711354, 1.12006525936429, 
0.636770955714099, 1.20754087091403, 0.791845392249831, 1.1755507928123, 
0.681217042180291, 1.17322395658813, 0.675244390301616, 1.36348537713933, 
1.07417558474477, -0.068430313534666, 1.08019795067758, 0.47038618934369, 
0.521107429716069, 0.482651259569048, 0.573592386846872, 0.922428279005258, 
0.165721243515427, 0.385694688986387, 0.551362682375665, -0.117354750364616, 
1.3168837696292, 0.522290759400617, 0.476744898537484, 0.377802643502404, 
0.684679934216977, 1.36583491854445, 0.580631004730677, 0.539972392301982, 
1.03119161251096, 0.82686270229947, 0.522366896147473, 0.481811274117581, 
1.25317892492354, 0.884653998710446, -0.749377267033438, 1.13515779802437, 
-0.112487015998199, 1.41812368189913, 0.700084748207621, 0.891842804137902, 
0.702757564431742, 0.734076268566994, 0.816010460696261, -0.184716040330949, 
-0.465181926681245, 0.568585655970242, 0.411752804691037, 0.810583157313205, 
0.554500820737744, -0.145349395370232, 1.49133874195868, 1.23056235160133, 
1.02549436830091, -0.839955549686024)), row.names = c(NA, -346L
), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(Country = c("Albania", "Algeria", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", 
"Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", 
"Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", 
"Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", 
"Cameroon", "Canada", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", 
"China", "China, Hong Kong SAR", "China, Macao SAR", "Colombia", 
"Comoros", "Congo", "Costa Rica", "Côte d'Ivoire", "Croatia", 
"Curaçao", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "D.R. of the Congo", "Denmark", 
"Djibouti", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", 
"Equatorial Guinea", "Estonia", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", 
"Finland", "France", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", 
"Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Haiti", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", 
"Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", 
"Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", 
"Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's DR", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", 
"Liberia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Malawi", 
"Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", 
"Mexico", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", "Mozambique", 
"Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
"Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "North Macedonia", "Norway", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", 
"Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Republic of Korea", "Republic of Moldova", 
"Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Lucia", "Sao Tome and Principe", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", 
"Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "Spain", 
"Sri Lanka", "St. Vincent and the Grenadines", "State of Palestine", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", 
"Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Thailand", "Togo", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
"Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "U.R. of Tanzania: Mainland", 
"Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", 
"United States of America", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", 
"Viet Nam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe", "Albania", "Algeria", 
"Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", 
"Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
"Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", 
"Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", 
"Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Central African Republic", 
"Chad", "Chile", "China", "China, Hong Kong SAR", "China, Macao SAR", 
"Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Costa Rica", "Côte d'Ivoire", 
"Croatia", "Curaçao", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "D.R. of the Congo", 
"Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", 
"El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Estonia", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", 
"Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", 
"Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Haiti", "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", 
"Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", 
"Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", 
"Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's DR", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", 
"Liberia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Malawi", 
"Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", 
"Mexico", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Morocco", "Mozambique", 
"Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", 
"Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "North Macedonia", "Norway", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", 
"Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Republic of Korea", "Republic of Moldova", 
"Romania", "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Lucia", "Sao Tome and Principe", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", 
"Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "Spain", 
"Sri Lanka", "St. Vincent and the Grenadines", "State of Palestine", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", 
"Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Thailand", "Togo", "Trinidad and Tobago", 
"Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "U.R. of Tanzania: Mainland", 
"Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", 
"United States of America", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", 
"Viet Nam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), outcomes = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("change_dependency_ratio_1990_2015", 
"change_dependency_ratio_1965_1990"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.398123161188132, 
0.0830910838830155, -0.0509010462858756, 0.14130939757635, 0.0309448471342206, 
0.212156096018974, 0.467114123861573, 0.242160484950692, 0.253948731466323, 
0.0388882219981139, 0.184086975367716, 0.0554969720621382, 0.024214947271092, 
0.403122685405711, 0.122196022985809, 0.221554441449814, 0.0105808383432469, 
-0.0350666654672087, 0.0237230699085401, 0.0542006723001102, 
0.396301148636019, 0.00479665619727526, 0.17613557364792, 0.158549300687729, 
0.222753904572088, -0.0679851322620935, -0.0253231953457055, 
-0.0867506561598986, 0.0406618446863762, -0.083315964393983, 
0.393556442177755, -0.0775416079610512, -0.0658887855682476, 
0.231645867769874, 0.229567396079183, 0.433009260575827, 0.294212666921972, 
0.188762457136509, -0.0265371130376149, -0.0263212095409177, 
0.214474587251249, -0.0139063070849487, 0.322621916655375, 0.587328280156014, 
0.120008191472176, 0.213159693532978, -0.00987639022713166, 0.290196653308586, 
0.045992636949827, 0.119538595241012, 0.120165701587676, -0.00708999590830717, 
0.104787443391876, -0.165762118505394, 0.241094479011241, -0.0040719308805422, 
-0.0267978243769081, 0.168850352663662, 0.44319872930422, 0.323540395295048, 
-0.23131326653667, -0.00875776820505886, 0.164852036810846, 0.374007815296586, 
0.00886861846944575, 0.206341509473451, 0.0545333305953083, -0.0212696351809918, 
-0.0498839597353738, -0.039324667932303, -0.0134550789380752, 
0.0146799292807489, 0.15773040039105, 0.257911755378933, 0.0770514810343421, 
0.0782733233080137, 0.0276023447303095, -0.077064515546113, 0.135642580624321, 
0.144829445263811, 0.319736193367588, 0.0904353552944108, 0.514329009047002, 
-0.0148943228589375, 0.0423996039440057, -0.0328708559176694, 
0.0858069299988889, -0.0532225891248916, -0.0227918426094847, 
0.261177457981367, 0.0172789840634143, -0.044950556774743, -0.0381052703009499, 
0.339264196021887, 0.0678084085627291, -0.018091746025337, -0.0454328686516391, 
0.110564793514707, -0.123460223196024, -0.107107285546687, 0.394036685146817, 
-0.0219956010018594, 0.358122825326543, 0.116941994109051, -0.0159830755685619, 
0.2769238725963, 0.113357348751862, -0.0995079697291118, 0.0830925437136069, 
-0.0231308148595351, 0.0818960835398407, 0.406916883761686, 0.283544729400408, 
0.0473232423265355, 0.0256750433301466, -0.0322884763794392, 
0.226824565750246, 0.143678691632955, -0.0525910860693484, -0.0192164663568681, 
0.145296134674028, 0.0777810924257498, 0.138812789996608, 0.108991312209926, 
0.255085975411616, 0.288899001012185, -0.0056058738464385, 0.411675880202299, 
0.0979338974291016, 0.158261393920507, 0.121463375174013, 0.03221558529891, 
0.0752098777829092, -0.108038719584569, 0.0451082001661763, -0.0488696890082719, 
0.264057297418888, 0.0744761732040302, -0.0808960422374715, 0.377536265597609, 
0.203639151129089, 0.360038671966065, 0.016648408952926, 0.187105929024774, 
0.256758186659192, 0.199214226926007, 0.0141836912145429, 0.0238674633141847, 
0.107634547878027, 0.158412785555059, 0.227923174333828, 0.0222261028045417, 
0.356964682522796, -0.0688202726456453, 0.334653694535773, -0.0360247564281497, 
0.251095568507597, 0.111701591703071, 0.107279630093633, 0.0181998814698253, 
-0.0227988569105966, -0.0504624773401749, 0.0704011548529228, 
0.00834067678623526, 0.17363275607521, 0.29244025856914, 0.0578621209808398, 
0.00152730146499902, 0.149545103984778, 0.0647895136705983, -0.0305648272827664, 
-0.0506354698086458, NA, -0.0292982602120182, -0.0745568714193291, 
-0.0158114995499791, -0.0526278674865631, 0.0895692260747208, 
0.0622753451174147, 0.0693631196029568, -0.043524303709262, -0.163336152067602, 
0.0220069231850007, -0.0372480350396547, -0.0127416788704636, 
0.00504322809867846, -0.211303990526285, 0.150689604961094, -0.0774764273136075, 
-0.107327548073341, -0.101653276820036, 0.0541427833880424, 0.0053919747731232, 
0.158611219787252, -0.0491640268190917, 0.00338102629153109, 
-0.155711219022126, 0.199503979128721, 0.000143811528831528, 
-0.0505998291341132, -0.0683908203869206, 0.00531631981392033, 
-0.0188264582510709, -0.00972775658891123, -0.0423089269872168, 
-0.0405244974334903, 0.0600854559092546, -0.00915296736548726, 
0.115110360580881, -0.171529225844077, -0.00248223661953856, 
-0.0232805426144127, -0.0525986053355909, 0.00558486661777702, 
0.0144074940917683, 0.14710582191989, 0.0316717285501824, -0.00945326566098326, 
-0.13736299087858, 0.0132915916588611, -0.050472174498465, 0.00652518868343993, 
0.0377821706637551, -0.0700536501269396, 0.00242593772672384, 
0.0509922622906901, -0.0590559970975604, 0.0550947644834419, 
-0.044565454128298, 0.0307192650398631, 0.018881004597837, 0.0235594502081332, 
-0.100079012305613, -0.0366233215469571, 0.00298230971394092, 
0.158094632962475, -0.0696033527255899, 0.00675969760095929, 
0.242793615992266, 0.0289955515148832, 0.0520204945268078, 0.00911963582072006, 
-0.069540427821399, 0.000208817704798414, -0.0342934097114747, 
0.0226814556538434, -0.0463245292019691, 0.00722298596780935, 
0.00718862780849888, -0.00066619912582111, -0.0767116018378476, 
-0.243121449034015, -0.0443807611718632, 0.0932646168511789, 
-0.0671773042384913, 0.284002072219196, -0.00547861010293765, 
0.0343447054170564, -0.111773356351767, 0.00322001522478446, 
-0.0587805770660498, 0.016093164362485, 0.0686994785554735, -0.0341956195178609, 
-0.0622551944564226, 0.0302916484213724, 0.0878515589816369, 
-0.0958075512267668, -0.0718260301242502, 0.00658730728919477, 
-0.0407145080805323, 0.126027524598038, 0.0353731549521963, -0.04687770096068, 
0.0194541107438475, 0.0472818974219094, -0.024043289427089, -0.120483950102178, 
0.161455102896429, 0.0435832542273855, 0.039171762761035, -0.0183988230174034, 
-0.044959894325082, 0.0246249760978033, -0.0464051312493554, 
-0.0398124625969878, 0.0232230074702894, 0.0418812430599326, 
0.0121811028455855, 0.112629852328967, -0.0953347596912298, -0.121894030853175, 
0.0175797098796357, -0.0048370366236079, -0.0305903547470887, 
-0.0183306921407706, -0.0641072715448618, 0.0318404615702211, 
0.149207705011576, -0.0596233194534432, 0.0187959558456414, 0.0918171139063938, 
0.133846112123352, 0.184054472200999, -0.0565179188347451, 0.0141032047121729, 
0.1361470326673, -0.128088011242165, 0.0315299754663041, 0.150424334795938, 
-0.0714527750333729, -0.00445779662263851, -0.0277364410930278, 
-0.0463879783356869, 0.00475683969862661, -0.0194317397134581, 
0.136516248539494, 0.0284509475772005, -0.110705732900706, -0.0517643559854549, 
-0.0216934415592076, -0.00598072520888693, -0.0201970082427561, 
0.00420968059751337, -0.0588788836438903, 0.0964065165788101, 
-0.0606627161874218, 0.0290743755043736, -0.00979923240980679, 
-0.00601622584197931, 0.0296275948272899, 0.015878161506364, 
-0.107568232847218, -0.000340675297749504, -0.0184271677103232, 
0.214065248760853, -0.0565794859933912, -0.0762034351837085, 
-0.0872304067027536, 0.154039412247359, -0.133206610906594, 0.0246356772631723, 
-0.0883994807900984, -0.0526459846319143, -0.021995026737945, 
-0.0624685869818875)), row.names = c(NA, -346L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is my code:

```
    df_ratio_stacked <- melt(df_ratio_stacked, id.var = c('Country'), variable.name = 'outcomes')
  df_gdp_stacked <- melt(df_gdp_stacked, id.var = c('Country'), variable.name = 'outcomes')
  #Merging
  df_stacked = merge(x=df_ratio_stacked,y=df_gdp_stacked, by='Country')
```

When I merge both data sets I get a duplicate of the Countries and outcomes, so there will be 4 rows instead of the 2 rows needed.

[image]

I tried to use function distinct, that works but only for one of the two. I mean that when i use distinct I cannot get rid of the duplicates for both outcome.x and outcome.y

I hope my question is a bit clear, and that someone is able to help!

Example of how it should look:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `merge` I think you should `rbind` the two datasets. For clarity you can then get the data in wide format so that you have only 1 row for each country.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  mutate(outcomes = sub('_\\d+_\\d+', '', outcomes)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = outcomes, values_from = value, 
              values_fn = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 173 x 3
#    Country             change_log_GDP_per_cap change_dependency_ratio
#   <chr>                                <dbl>                   <dbl>
# 1 Albania                            1.16                    0.184  
# 2 Algeria                            0.462                   0.00427
# 3 Angola                             0.674                  -0.0334 
# 4 Antigua and Barbuda                0.376                   0.0443 
# 5 Argentina                          0.811                   0.0603 
# 6 Armenia                            0.398                   0.137  
# 7 Aruba                             -0.00254                 0.268  
# 8 Australia                          0.518                   0.0993 
# 9 Austria                            0.737                   0.0453 
#10 Azerbaijan                         0.729                   0.0304 
# … with 163 more rows
```

---

A different way to represent the data can be using nesting -

```
df1 %>%
  nest(data1 = -Country) %>%
  inner_join(df2 %>%
  nest(data2 = -Country), by = 'Country') %>%
  unnest_wider(col = data1, names_sep = '_') %>%
  unnest_wider(col = data2, names_sep = '_') %>%
  unnest(cols = -Country)

# A tibble: 346 x 5
#   Country             data1_outcomes                   data1_value data2_outcomes                    data2_value
#   <chr>               <fct>                                  <dbl> <fct>                                   <dbl>
# 1 Albania             change_log_GDP_per_cap_1965_1990      NA     change_dependency_ratio_1990_2015      0.398 
# 2 Albania             change_log_GDP_per_cap_1990_2015       1.16  change_dependency_ratio_1965_1990     -0.0293
# 3 Algeria             change_log_GDP_per_cap_1965_1990       0.579 change_dependency_ratio_1990_2015      0.0831
# 4 Algeria             change_log_GDP_per_cap_1990_2015       0.345 change_dependency_ratio_1965_1990     -0.0746
# 5 Angola              change_log_GDP_per_cap_1965_1990      NA     change_dependency_ratio_1990_2015     -0.0509
# 6 Angola              change_log_GDP_per_cap_1990_2015       0.674 change_dependency_ratio_1965_1990     -0.0158
# 7 Antigua and Barbuda change_log_GDP_per_cap_1965_1990      NA     change_dependency_ratio_1990_2015      0.141 
# 8 Antigua and Barbuda change_log_GDP_per_cap_1990_2015       0.376 change_dependency_ratio_1965_1990     -0.0526
# 9 Argentina           change_log_GDP_per_cap_1965_1990       0.495 change_dependency_ratio_1990_2015      0.0309
#10 Argentina           change_log_GDP_per_cap_1990_2015       1.13  change_dependency_ratio_1965_1990      0.0896
# … with 336 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that I need the categories 'change log GDP per capita' and 'change in dependency ratio' stacked underneath each other. So that I get two columns for these two categories, but then without duplicates. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: But you have two values of 'change log GDP per capita' (change_log_GDP_per_cap_1965_1990 and change_log_GDP_per_cap_1990_2015) and same for 'change in dependency ratio'. What do you want to do of them? Take average of them ? See my updated answer.

Comment: No, I would like to have a dataframe structured for all countries as you can see in this red rectangle (I will edit it in the main post). So for every country 2 rows with the different columns. Hopefully you can help me!

Comment: See the updated answer. Is that the format you want the data to be?